# Way to modify JS string containing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, xpath

In JS I have HTML page as value of string variable. I need to remove all styles from that page.

I could do so:

```
$(data).find("link[rel=stylesheet]").remove()
```

but if I understood correctly jQuery find only inside body.

- I do not want to use regex. I am sure that there is a simple solution.
- I think maybe there's a way to use XPath.

Give me a way to do it, please!

**My code:**

```
Y.io.request('' + dataUrl, {
    dataType: 'html',
    method: 'get',
    cache: 'true',
    on: {
        success: function () {
            var data = this.get('responseData');
            child.setContent(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Data is HTML page. I need to remove styles from it before inserting into child.

Comment: show your full code and explain your problem better

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not clear but if you want to remove all stylesheets from a HTML page just do this;

```
$('html').find("link[rel=stylesheet]").remove()
```

jQuery does not find only inside body, it could handle any element of the DOM including the entire `<html>` or the `<head>`.

So if your var `data` looks something like this:

```
'<html> <head> ... </head> <body> ... </body> </html>'
```

The selector that you wrote will work perfectly.

Comment: You understand me correctly. But it does not work. It returns empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, jQuery kinda chokes if you want it to parse an entire DOM and treat it like HTML directly. That said, if you have some assurance as to the well-formedness of the returned HTML page (mainly, is it valid XML?), then we can do a little bit of a hacky workaround by treating the page content like an XML document. Take a look at this sample code:

```
var content = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"></link></head><body>hello</body></html>';
// $xml now has a jquery wrapped xml doc
var $xml = $($.parseXML(content));
// find the stylesheets and remove them
$xml.find("link[rel=stylesheet]").remove();
// $xml.contents() contains the jquery wrapped doc-content (i.e. the <html> tag and its contents)
console.log($xml.contents()[0].outerHTML);
```

The final console.log should output the HTML content of the page (minus the link nodes, which we remove in line 5).

Note again the caveat that **the HTML content must be valid XML for this to work**. That means including closing tags :-)

edit: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rgsaz33e/1/